# unix env command can't find file even though its in the current directory

Tags: command-line, environment

I'm having a problem with calling env from the terminal. I'm running the latest Ubuntu OS. Here's what happens:

```
$ ls
disarm.ss  hereis.ss  mat.ss  README  sg.ss  start-test  syntax.ss
$ env SCHEMEHEAPDIRS=/usr/lib/csv8.1/i3le sg.ss
env: sg.ss: No such file or directory
```

I have checked that the path /usr/lib/csv8.1/i3le is correct. Here are the permissions of the files in this dir:

```
$ ls -l
total 60
-rw------- 1 dtdannen dtdannen 17375 2011-03-29 23:05 disarm.ss
-rw------- 1 dtdannen dtdannen  9410 2011-03-29 23:05 hereis.ss
-rw------- 1 dtdannen dtdannen  9955 2011-03-29 23:05 mat.ss
-rw------- 1 dtdannen dtdannen   394 2011-03-29 23:05 README
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dtdannen dtdannen  2801 2011-03-29 23:05 sg.ss
-rwx------ 1 dtdannen dtdannen   137 2011-03-29 23:05 start-test
-rw------- 1 dtdannen dtdannen   678 2011-03-29 23:05 syntax.ss
```

I can't seem to figure out why env cannot find 'sg.ss'. Is it a problem with permissions? I know you should rarely if ever 'chmod 777' on a file (here I did so on sg.ss), but I just wanted to see if that would make it work. I need to call this command within a python program, not directly via command line, but I get the same error in both cases, so I used the terminal as my example.

Any and all advice is appreciated :)

P.S. I searched SO for at least 20 minutes and couldn't find a similar post. Hope I'm not re-asking something.

EDIT: Tried the same thing but with ./sg.ss instead of just sg.ss (still didn't work, same error :( )

Comment: search on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Unix is not DOS. If `.` (or an empty entry) is not in `PATH`, the current directory will not be searched. This is by design, so you don't get trojaned just by being in the wrong directory. :-)

Comment: Are you sure the file is named `sg.ss`? Try `ls sg.ss`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the first line in the file sg.ss
it most likely starts #!/blah
check that /blah exists.

Answer (score 1):

`env` will search the PATH environment variable to search for your utility, just as your shell's native behavior. Use `./` if you want to refer to the file in current directory, i.e.:

```
env SCHEMEHEAPDIRS=/usr/lib/csv8.1/i3le ./sg.ss
```

Comment: @yan, Right, I tried that and it didn't change anything. Still received the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The current directory isn't on the search path, and as `sg.ss` doesn't contain any slashes, it's taken to be a name to look for in the path (much like the behavior of `execl`. You want `env SCHEMEHEAPDIRS=/usr/lib/csv8.1/i3le ./sg.ss`.

Comment: @hobbs,Right, I tried that and it didn't change anything. Still received the same error